# how to accept blanks when websites format differently

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm not sure how to handle when a website changes format.

Usually the html of the website is the first lot of HTML however sometimes it is the bottom bit of HTML below where data moves and adds an extra table data row.

```
<td>
<strong>Track Rating:</strong>
"GOOD"
</td>
<td>
<strong>Gross Time:</strong>
" 1:56.2"
</td>
```

```
<td>
<strong>Track Rating:</strong>
"GOOD"
</td>
<td></td>
<td>
<strong>Gross Time:</strong>
" 1:56.2"
</td>
```

My code looks like this where im trying to fill it as blank if it moves, however i presume it doesn't work due to me using the findnext function.

Im trying to just get the "GOOD" and 1:56.2 from the code

Any ideas as i'm stumped?

```
trackrating = tableoftimes.find(text="Track Rating:").findPrevious('td').contents[1]
                if not trackrating:
                    trackrating = ''
grosstime = tableoftimes.find(text="Track Rating:").findNext('td').contents[1]
                if not grosstime:
                    grosstime = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = """<td>
<strong>Track Rating:</strong>
"GOOD"
</td>
<td>
<strong>Gross Time:</strong>
" 1:56.2"
</td>"""
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
trackrating = doc.getElementByText('Track Rating:',tag='strong').nextText()
grosstime = doc.getElementByText('Gross Time:',tag='strong').nextText()
print(trackrating,grosstime)
```

Result:

```
"GOOD" " 1:56.2"
```

Comment: ok - could my best bet but not sure on SimplifiedDoc - 
How would i initialise my html to Simplified doc? and what will it do above with the blank td line? ignore it? 
```results = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'forPrint'})
    results = SimplifiedDoc(results)```

Comment: div = SimplifiedDoc(html).select('div.forPrint')
trackrating = div.getElementByText('Track Rating:',tag='strong').nextText()
grosstime = div.getElementByText('Gross Time:',tag='strong').nextText()

Comment: @BradLangtry Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples